# Trouble plotting .txt data using Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am reading a .txt file using pd.read_csv and then I want to plot the data using plt.plot.
But the plotted diagram doesn't show the actual data and has many black boxes besides it. I am not sure what the problem is and I can't find any solution online.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv('data/srj.txt', delimiter = '\t')
print(data.head())
print(data.columns)

         Depth     Hardness Young's Modulus
0           nm          GPa             GPa
1  3.946207852  0.019199189     10.32950876
2  4.041822876  0.020595101     9.994030663
3  4.110927096  0.021792856     10.21552158
4  4.210582215  0.024678833     10.42801355  #.head

Index(['Depth', 'Hardness', 'Young's Modulus'], dtype='object') #columns

x = data['Depth']
y = data['Hardness']

plt.plot(x,y, 'r-', label = 'Depth-Hardness')
plt.xlabel('Depth [nm]')
plt.ylabel('Hardness [GPa]')
plt.title('Depth-Hardness-Curve')
plt.show()
```

[image: the resulting plot]

This is the resulting plot and it doesn't fit with the data. Is there anything wrong with my code? I guess it might have to to with the nm and GPa in the first row but removing them didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Plot some of rows of data.

Comment: The reason you're seeing this is because you are plotting text.

Comment: Is the column data float? Try `data.info()` and check. The first row appears to have `nm`, 'GPa`, which might make the data string, instead of float.

Answer (score 0):

The second row in the file is not numeric. Use `skiprows`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/srj.txt', delimiter = '\t', skiprows=[1], header=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. I thought I tried it before but i guess i didnt.